# Existence of regular semisimple elements in linear group over local field

Tags: nt.number-theory, gr.group-theory, linear-algebra, algebraic-groups, profinite-groups

Let $ L $ be a finite extension of $p$-adic numbers $ \mathbb{Q}_p $. Let $ \text{GL}_{n}(L) $ denote the general linear group $ \text{GL}_{n}(L) $ over $L$ equipped with the topology induced from the $p$-adic field $ L$. An element $ g\in \text{GL}_{n}(L) $ is called *regular semisimple* if it has pairwise distinct eigenvalues in the algebraic closure $ \overline{\mathbb{Q}}_{p} $ of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. A *linear group* over $L$ is a subgroup of $ \text{GL}_{n}(L) $.

My question is the following: When does a linear group $ \Gamma $ have a regular semisimple element?

As pointed out in the comments, it is not the case only under the assumption that $ \Gamma $ has no open solvable subgroup.

Comment: "has distinct" means "has at least two distinct" or "has pairwise distinct"? (given the title, you probably mean the latter)

Comment: A trivial counterexample would then be the diagonal copy of $\mathrm{GL}_2$ in $\mathrm{GL}_4$.

Comment: here "has distinct" refer to "has pairwise distinct".

Comment: Thanks for your counterexample! Maybe this question is too stupid. Do you know any sufficient condition to ensure that such an element exists in a linear group?

Comment: If the subgroup is irreducible, that should be true and should follow from the proof of the Tits alternative.

Comment: "subgroup is irreducible" means " if the representation $\Gamma \to \text{GL}_n(L)$ is irreducible" or "it is an irreducible topological space"? Is it possible to point out references or a more detailed explanation, thanks!

Comment: Probably it would be useful to clarify the meaning of "linear group" for such a question.

Answer (score 1):

The group $\mathrm{GL}_N(\mathbf{Q}_p)$ acts by conjugation on trace zero matrices, and the corresponding subgroup
$$\Gamma \subset \mathrm{GL}_{N^2 - 1}(\mathbf{Q}_p)$$ (which is isomorphic to $\mathrm{PGL}_N(\mathbf{Q}_p)$) is both absolutely irreducible and has the property that every element $\gamma \in \Gamma$ has $1$ as an eigenvalue with multiplicity at least $N-1$.

Comment: What exactly is group $ \Gamma$?

Comment: @YufanLuo If a group $G$ acts on a vector space $V$, there is a map

$$G \rightarrow \mathrm{GL}(V)$$

and it has some image. In this case, $G = \mathrm{GL}_N(\mathbf{Q}_p)$, $V = M^0(\mathbf{Q}_p)$ is the space of trace zero matrices which is a vector space of dimension $N^2 - 1$, so there is a map 

$$\mathrm{GL}_N(\mathbf{Q}_p) \rightarrow \mathrm{GL}_{N^2-1}(\mathbf{Q}_p),$$

the image is then some group $\Gamma$. The kernel of the map above is the center (scalar matrices) and so $\Gamma$ is identified with $\mathrm{PGL}_N(\mathbf{Q}_p)$. I'm not sure I can say it any simpler.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. So, you give an (absolutely) irreducible linear group containing no open solvable subgroup but it does not contain an element which has pairwise distinct eigenvalues?

Comment: @YufanLuo, I really suggest you think a little harder about this basic example. This is just group theory and elementary linear algebra and it gives a counter-example to even a weaker version of the problem. Then you went and wrote an "answer" which contradicts this example so is obviously wrong.

Comment: But why your $\Gamma$ is contained in $\text{GL}_{N^2-1}(\mathbb{Z}_p)$?

Comment: @YufanLuo:

1. There is nothing in your question which requires, mentions, or asks that $\Gamma$ to be a subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_{n}(\mathbf{Z}_p)$ rather than $\mathrm{GL}_{n}(\mathbf{Q}_p)$. From your question "A linear group is a subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_n(L)$". Second, if you want an example in $\mathrm{GL}_{n}(\mathbf{Z}_p)$ you can trivially modify the construction by taking the image of $\mathrm{GL}_N(\mathbf{Z}_p)$ rather than $\mathrm{GL}_N(\mathbf{Q}_p)$.

Comment: @YufanLuo Do you have any further questions?

Comment: I think you are right. It would be great if you could give some sufficient condition.